# Check if the input string consisting of braces is well-formed

Tags: c

I have spent the last two hours trying to debug my code that is supposed to check if the input consists of well-formed brackets. What I mean by well formed is that `()()[]` or `([()])` are acceptable but `((((()` is not.

I'm not allowed to use any header file apart from `<stdio.h>`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cross(char str[], int i, int j) {
    str[i] = 'X';
    str[j] = 'X';
}

int iscrossed(char str[]) { 
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] != 'X')
            return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int check(char str[]) {
    int i = 1, j;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] == ')') {
            for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (str[j] == '(') {
                    cross(str, str[i], str[j]);
                }
                break;
            }
        } else
        if (str[i] == ']') {
            for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (str[j] == '[') {
                    cross(str, str[i], str[j]);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (iscrossed(str) == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main() {
    char str[20];
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%d\n", check(str));
}
```

For certain inputs the program prints a zero followed by a segmentation fault and for the others it just prints a zero.
Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner programmer so please don't include too much heavy stuff in your hints. I'd be grateful for any help on this.

**Edit:** It would be wonderful if your answer tells me the errors in *my* code, because that was my question in the first place.

Comment: Classic question. I suggest search and read about stacks. That helps.

Comment: Is something like `([)]` acceptable or do they also have to make sense syntax-wise?

Comment: @Lundin Nope, `([)]` is not acceptable.

Comment: Then I think you need something like a binary expression tree to keep track of previously open braces. Otherwise the algorithm will have to re-search for the previous open brace and turn out very slow.

Comment: is it ok for you to import `stdlib.h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you call `cross(str, str[i], str[j]);` instead of `cross(str, i, j);` when you find matches for parentheses and brackets.
- the `break` statement should be moved inside the `if` block.
- your method does not allow detection of nesting errors
- your method would have undefined behavior if `str` is an empty string (which you cannot input via `scanf()`)

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cross(char str[], int i, int j) {
    str[i] = str[j] = 'X';
}

int iscrossed(char str[]) { 
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] != 'X')
            return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int check(char str[]) {
    int i = 0, j;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] == ')') {
            for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (str[j] == '(') {
                    cross(str, i, j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else
        if (str[i] == ']') {
            for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (str[j] == '[') {
                    cross(str, i, j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return iscrossed(str);
}

int main() {
    char str[80];
    if (scanf("%79s", str) == 1) {
        printf("%d\n", check(str));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a simpler alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *check(const char str[], int endc) {
    while (str) {
        int c = *str++;
        switch (c) {
          case '(': str = check(str, ')'); break;
          case '[': str = check(str, ']'); break;
          case '{': str = check(str, '}'); break;
          case ')':
          case ']':
          case '}':
          case '\0': return c == endc ? str : NULL;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    char str[80];
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        printf("%d\n", check(str, '\0') != NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a simple recursive solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int brace(const char **s, char cc)
{
  while(1) {
    if(**s == cc) { return 0; }
    switch(**s) {
      case '\0': return -1;
      case '[': ++(*s); if(brace(s, ']')) { return -1; } ++(*s); break;
      case '{': ++(*s); if(brace(s, '}')) { return -1; } ++(*s); break;
      case '(': ++(*s); if(brace(s, ')')) { return -1; } ++(*s); break;
      case ']':
      case '}':
      case ')': return -1;
      default: ++(*s);
    }
  }
}

int check_brace(const char *s)
{
  return brace(&s, '\0');
}


int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", check_brace(" hekl(l o{ asdf } te)ts()({})"));
}
```

Returns `-1` when somethings wrong. Otherwise `0`.

Comment: What is `brackets()`?

Comment: @Shawn this was a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode of a possible answer:

```
initialize char[] unclosed
int latest_unclosed_index = -1
for each char in string {
   if char == opening_bracket {
      latest_unclosed_index += 1
      unclosed[latest_unclosed_index] = char
   } else if char == closing_bracket {
      if latest_unclosed_index < 0 {
         return false
      } else if char == closing_of(unclosed[latest_unclosed_index]) {
         unclosed[latest_unclosed_index] = null
         latest_unclosed_index -= 1
      } else {
         return false
      }
      
   }
}
if latest_unclosed_index == -1 {
   return true
} else {
   return false
}
```

This works by keeping an array of all unclosed opening brackets in the order that you encounter them in, and removing them whenever you encounter a closing bracket, as a sort of stack.

This solution has a complexity of O(n).

A problem with this implementation is that there is an unknown amount of brackets in string, which may cause the array to overflow if it isn't large enough.

Solution:

- To be sure that this solution doesn't overflow, the size of the array should be at least half the size of the input string, and you'll have to check at each character if there are enough characters left in the input string to be able to completely close all brackets.
- Use a list implementation (or write your own) instead of an array for `unclosed`.

Comment: Just keeping track of a single "latest unclosed" will fail if you have nested parantheses like `(())`: The inner parens are checked, but the outer ones aren't, because the "latest unclosed" will be −1.

Comment: I do keep track of the outer brackets, with the `unclosed` array. `latest_enclosed` is merely an index into the `unclosed` array.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're right, of course. I missed the array.

Comment: No problem. I have changed `latest_enclosed` to `latest_enclosed_index` for more clarity, because you made me realize that the previous name wasn't very clear.

Comment: Instead of an array you can also make it recursive and use the actual stack.

Answer (score 1):

### If its ok for you to use `stdlib.h` then,

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define bool int

// structure of a stack node
struct sNode {
    char data;
    struct sNode* next;
};

// Function to push an item to stack
void push(struct sNode** top_ref, int new_data);

// Function to pop an item from stack
int pop(struct sNode** top_ref);

// Returns 1 if character1 and character2 are matching left
// and right Brackets
bool isMatchingPair(char character1, char character2)
{
    if (character1 == '(' && character2 == ')')
        return 1;
    else if (character1 == '{' && character2 == '}')
        return 1;
    else if (character1 == '[' && character2 == ']')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

// Return 1 if expression has balanced Brackets
bool areBracketsBalanced(char exp[])
{
    int i = 0;

    // Declare an empty character stack
    struct sNode* stack = NULL;

    // Traverse the given expression to check matching
    // brackets
    while (exp[i])
    {
        // If the exp[i] is a starting bracket then push
        // it
        if (exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '[')
            push(&stack, exp[i]);

        // If exp[i] is an ending bracket then pop from
        // stack and check if the popped bracket is a
        // matching pair*/
        if (exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ')'
            || exp[i] == ']') {

            // If we see an ending bracket without a pair
            // then return false
            if (stack == NULL)
                return 0;

            // Pop the top element from stack, if it is not
            // a pair bracket of character then there is a
            // mismatch.
            // his happens for expressions like {(})
            else if (!isMatchingPair(pop(&stack), exp[i]))
                return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // If there is something left in expression then there
    // is a starting bracket without a closing
    // bracket
    if (stack == NULL)
        return 1; // balanced
    else
        return 0; // not balanced
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    char exp[100] = "{()}[]";

    // Function call
    if (areBracketsBalanced(exp))
        printf("Balanced \n");
    else
        printf("Not Balanced \n");
    return 0;
}

// Function to push an item to stack
void push(struct sNode** top_ref, int new_data)
{
    // allocate node
    struct sNode* new_node
        = (struct sNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct sNode));

    if (new_node == NULL) {
        printf("Stack overflow n");
        getchar();
        exit(0);
    }

    // put in the data
    new_node->data = new_data;

    // link the old list off the new node
    new_node->next = (*top_ref);

    // move the head to point to the new node
    (*top_ref) = new_node;
}

// Function to pop an item from stack
int pop(struct sNode** top_ref)
{
    char res;
    struct sNode* top;

    // If stack is empty then error
    if (*top_ref == NULL) {
        printf("Stack overflow n");
        getchar();
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        top = *top_ref;
        res = top->data;
        *top_ref = top->next;
        free(top);
        return res;
    }
}
```

### Features

- Support nested parantheses like `(())`
- Support bad nestings such as `([)]`
- Commented but not by me (see the below spoiler)

> Note: i feel guilty that i have copied code from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/)

## The algorithm

[image]

## Pseudocode Like Block code!

[image]

> If it's not ok for you to use `stdlib.h`,then someone may edit this code and remove the errors that occur when we remove that line(`#include <stdlib.h>`),I am not a `c` guy and i don't know to edit,i just copy pasted !

Comment: Unfortunately `stdlib.h` is not allowed. Nevertheless your answer was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I am sure this code will work,I have added a block coding as well,you can convert to c,i am converting the code now

Comment: @AmbicaGovind Here is the [link](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/656885270/editor/) for that block project ,for you to test

Answer (score 0):

First attempt didn't worked with bad nesting, as MOehm wrote in the comments.
Storing the opened braces that not have been closed yet helps to recognize bad nesting. The last opened brace will determine which closing brace is need.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check(char str[], int size)
{
    char opened[size/2];
    char close;
    int i = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int error = 0;
    
    while((i < size) || (pos < size/2))
    {
        if((str[i] == '(') || (str[i] == '['))
        {
            opened[pos] = str[i];
            pos++;
        }
        else if((str[i] == ')') || (str[i] == ']'))
        {
            if(str[i] == close)
            {
                opened[pos-1] = 0;
                pos--;
            }
            else
            {
                error = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n", opened);
        if(pos > 0)
        {
            switch(opened[pos-1])
            {
                case '(':
                    close = ')';
                    break;
                    
                case '[':
                    close = ']';
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
            close = 0;
            
        i++;
    }
    return error;
}

int main() {
    char str[20];
    printf("%d\n", check(str, sizeof(str)));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just counting braces and parens separately will fail for bad nestings such as `([)]`, which should be unbalanced.

Comment: @MOehm you're right, I have to improve this.

Comment: Curiously, there was another answer that did just this (with curlies added), but it was deleted.

Comment: @MOehm the other answer had also one additional issue. But I think we had the same not well thought out idea.